# Do browsers follow 301 redirects from HTTP to HTTPS, on a secure site?

Tags: security, redirect, https, browser-security

If I load a page `https://example.org` over HTTPS that contains references to HTTP resources like

```
 <script src="http://example.org/script.js"></script>
```

I understand that the browser refuses to load the script unless it's `src="https://example.org/script.js"`.

My question is, **if I implement a 301 redirect** from `http://example.org/script.js` to `https://example.org/script.js`, will the browser follow the redirect and load the script via HTTPS, or will it still refuse to load it?

Comment: Why not just change the `<script>` tag to use `src="script.js"` instead? You are already loading a page at `example.org`, so you can load `script.js` using a relative URL instead of an absolute URL. If you have to use an absolute URL, you can at least omit the protocol scheme so the browser uses the scheme used to access the current page, eg: `src="//example.org/script.js"`. Let the browser decide whether to use HTTP or HTTPS as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know that but what I need to know is if my site-wide HTTPS redirect is going to stop pages working before we have had a chance to go through and change all the absolute links to relative or protocol-relative links.

Comment: Instead of asking about it, it would have been a lot faster to just test it live and see what really happens.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yep, but I want to know if the behaviour is consistent across browsers and if it will remain so. I can (and will) test my particular case but I think a general answer to the question is valuable for others.

Comment: The behavior is likely to NOT be consistent between different browsers, as they implement security policies differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe browsers that block mixed content will still block a script from HTTP->HTTPS redirect.

They certainly should do, because it's not secure. An attacker could have intercepted the HTTP request and changed it to redirect to an HTTPS address that is not the one the page referencing the script intended.

Comment: But in that case, you are dealing with cross-domain access, which is handled by a separate set of security policies.  As long as the script is on the same domain as the referring page, there is no MITM attack vector (unless the MITM has access to the webserver itself, in which case you have bigger problems to deal with).

Comment: Browser will happily include `<script>` from a different domain, HTTPS or no. Even redirecting to the same server there are risks in including a different script from the one intended (especially if attacker can upload a resource of any type that can contain JavaScript-parsable content). The additional MITM risk is from an attacker with access to any of the networks between the user and the site sabotaging the unprotected HTTP 302 request.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Out of interest why doesn't the browser just request `https://` whenever it sees mixed content, and avoid making a HTTP request entirely? If the server doesn't respond then it's no worse than blocking it.